# What is the recommended method, for dynamically loading a partial view, that has dropdowns with content from db

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a List and I load on my Edit page, with the possibility of adding more. The Partial View has numerous dropdowns which are currently populated via the ViewBag.  Everything works fine on initial load, however, when I use the Add to append another partial via ajax, the dropdowns throw a specific error.

> 'The ViewData item that has the key 'UserTypeId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.'

I feel there must be a better way to do this but my Googling has failed me.  Any help would be appreciated.

The Controller

```
//UserTypes is List<UserType>
//int ID
//string Name 
ViewBag.ListUserTypes = new SelectList(UserTypes, "ID", "Name");
        public ActionResult CreateNewQuotesMentions()
    {
        var model = new QuoteMention();

        return PartialView("~/Views/master/newsalert/_QuotesMentions.cshtml", model);
    }
```

The ViewModel

```
 public List<QuoteMention> QuotesMentions { get; set; }
```

The View

```
<div id="QuotesMentions">
    @foreach (var item in Model.QuotesMentions)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Master/NewsAlert/_QuotesMentions.cshtml", item)
    }
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" name="addQuotesMentions" id="addQuotesMentions" value="Add" />
</div>
```

The .JS

```
$("#addQuotesMentions").on('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/en/master/news-alert/CreateNewQuotesMentions',
        success: function (partialView) {
            $('#QuotesMentions').append(partialView);
        }
    });

});

$(document).on('click', ".btn-delete", function (e) {
    var container = $(this).closest('.box');
    var id = container.data('id');
    if (!id) {
        container.remove();
    } else {
        // see notes below
    }

});
```

ThePartialView

```
@model Portal.Business.QuoteMention

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("NewQuotes"))
{
<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserType, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserTypeId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListUserTypes,
    "-- Please Select --", new { @class = "form-control", style="width:100%;"}
    )
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what `UserTypes` contains? If you put a breakpoint on `Html.DropDownListFor`, is ViewBag.ListUserTypes initialized?

Comment: I updated the code.The DropdownFor has a List<SelectItem> on first load, then is Null for any ajax calls.

Comment: Please include `CreateNewQuotesMentions` method also.

Comment: Updated, though i'm thinking someone is going to tell me that i need to re-pass the ViewBag through CreateNewQuotesMentions() each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your `ViewBag` is cleaned while your `CreateNewQuotesMentions` method executes.

A possible fix would be to re-populate `ViewBag.ListUserTypes`.
I also suggest to take a look at `TempData`. There are situation where it can save you. You can read about it [here](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/mvc-when-to-use-keep-vs-peek-in-asp-net-mvc/).